# Read and write from and to a cell in a bookmarked table

Tags: vba, ms-word, cell, bookmarks

I have a table 5 rows down and 3 columns across. I have bookmarked my table and have been trying to access a cell directly but cannot.
The first column are To:, From:, Re:, etc. I can find, let's say From:. I can get the cell information row and column. Let's say that's 2,1. I can't access 2,2 to put text into that cell.

It does not allow me to do activedocument.bookmarks("MyTable").row(2,2)... or activedocument.bookmarks("MyTable").range.row(2,2)...

I am wondering if I bookmarked it wrong.
I have selected the table by the + handle and bookmarked it.
I have then tried to only select the cells in the table and bookmarked it with no good results.

But either way I can put the bookmarked table into a range and I can get the accurate row and column count both ways. I just cant access the individual cells in the range directly.

Any tips?

Comment: I'm not sure how you have your bookmark set up but you can try `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyTable").Range.Tables(1).Cell(2,2)` or `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyTable").Cell(2,2)`

Comment: I was surprised that msgbox ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyTable").Range.Tables(1).Cell(2,2) worked with no .text or .value but it did allow me to read it. The second line I had tried already and Cell is not valid in that dot notation. I'm looking to see how I can write to it now.

Comment: Thank You. I did get it to work the way I wanted. It is a bit bulky compared to other programs but I have been able to have multiple tables with the bookmarks on one page.